# Regarding the usage of functions with array subscript

Tags: c, pointers

Can some one explain me the logic with respect to the value of the variable `b`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char buffer[4] = {1,2,3,4};   /* Declare the buffer */

unsigned char* u8GetHeader(void)
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;              /* incrementing the value of count for every invoke */
    if(1 == count)
      return &buffer[0];
    else
      return &buffer[1];
}

int main()
{
     unsigned int a , b;
     a = (u8GetHeader())[0];
     b = (u8GetHeader())[1];
     printf("The value of variable a = %d\n",a);
     printf("The value of variable b = %d\n",b);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the value of b as 3 while i was expecting the value as 2

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245419/regarding-the-return-of-a-function-using-array-subscript)?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local which has gone out of scope, and when you try to de-reference it you get undefined behavoir

Comment: Why were you expecting the value as 2?

Comment: And actually you made the code even worse, since now it's neither valid C *nor* valid C++.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++ ?

Comment: BTW this code looks pretty weird. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello All, Lets assume that the buffer is global . Can you please let me know why is the value of b coming as 3 instead of 2

Comment: As I said in a comment to your previous question (never post the same question multiple times!) use pen and paper to draw out the array as a series of squares. Then use arrows to draw the pointers to it. Then new arrows for the indexing in the `main` function.

Comment: IMO you really need to spend some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I need to decode a logic in my stack . How does (u8GetHeader())[1]; return 3?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for the information . Can you please re-check the question which i have edited .

Answer (score 3):

This program is a good candidate for working out on paper first and then stepping through the program to see if it matches your expectations.

Let us assume `buffer` is a global at address 0x1000.

The first call to u8GetHeader returns the address of `buffer[0]`, which is just `buffer` or 0x1000. You then index it with 0, so you access the number at 0x1000 which is 1.

The second call returns the address of `buffer[1]`, or 0x1001. You index it with 1, so you access the number at 0x1002, which is 3.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation . I understand the logic now

Answer (score 2):

Why b gives you 3: Since count is static it will increment on each call. With `b = (u8GetHeader())[1];` you call the function a second time so `&buffer[1]` is returned which is a pointer to `{2,3,4}` and its second value is 3.

Comment: That was a simple logic which i failed to understand . Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Lets modify your program a little:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int a , b;
    unsigned int *x, *y;

    x = u8GetHeader();
    y = u8GetHeader();
    a = x[0];
    b = y[1];
    printf("The value of variable a = %d\n",a);
    printf("The value of variable b = %d\n",b);
}
```

The first time the `u8GetHeader` function is called it returns a pointer to the first element of the array. This gets assigned to the `x` variable.

Each time after the first call, the `u8GetHeader` function will return a pointer to the second element. This gets assigned to the `y` variable.

Now if we "draw" the array and the pointers to the different elements in it it could look like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
^   ^
|   |
x   y
```

It should be pretty clear that `y` is pointing to the value `2`. That is `y[0] == 2`. From this it should also be quite clear that adding `1` to that index (i.e. `y[1]`) will then get the second element from `y`, which is the value `3`. So `y[1] == 3`.

---

Perhaps it is also useful to know that for *any* array of pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`.

From this we get that `y[1]` then must be `*(y + 1)`., and if we add an arrow for `y + 1` in the drawing we get:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
^   ^   ^
|   |   |
x   y   y+1
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.